# Calling a static jar class method from command line

Tags: java, command-line, jar, static-methods

I have a jar file : "CallMeMaybe.jar".

There is a static method callMe() in the main class callmemaybe.CallMeMaybe .
Like it is possible to call the main() method from command line by running :

```
java -cp CallMeMaybe.jar callmemaybe.CallMeMaybe
```

Is there a way to directly call another static method than main() ?

I would like to do that :

```
java -cp CallMeMaybe.jar callmemaybe.CallMeMaybe.callMe()
```

Comment: `main`, is the *main* entry point. Is there a `main` method anywhere in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call it **directly**, but just call it from your main method i.e.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething(args);
    }

    private static void doSomething(String[] args) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Although I don't see the point of the extra method.

Comment: But what if you return a true/false value?  You can't return a boolean from main