# Calling a Static Java Method from Perl

Tags: perl

We got a requirement to call a static method inside a Java class via perl script and capture the return value of the method as we have to remove the syso statements in the Java code.

Sample Java class

```
public class SampleClass
{
   public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception   
   {
       var_1 = func(arg1,arg2);       
       System.out.print(var_1);
    }
    private static String func(final String arg1, final String arg2)
    throws Exception
    { 

        <--- code -->

        return value;
     }

     public static String SampleMethod(final String arg1, final String arg2)
     throws Exception
     {     
         var_2 = func(arg1,arg2);
         return var_2;
     }
}
```

Intially in perl we are calling the actual class like below

```
command = SampleClass Arg_1  Arg 2 
`$command`
```

Now the requirement is to call the `SampleMethod` and capture the return value to avoid reading the o/p from console.

Tried the below

```
command = SampleClass.SampleMethod Arg_1  Arg 2 
`$command`
```

But it failed saying unable to load main class in `SampleMethod`

Please advise.

Comment: *"in perl we are calling the actual class like below: command = SampleClass Arg_1  Arg 2 "* : This is not valid Perl syntax. Please clarify

Comment: *"We got a requirement to call a static method inside a Java class via perl script.."* : Please show the Perl script you use.

Comment: See also [Calling a static jar class method from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25061695/2173773)

Comment: I think you need to wrap the static method inside another class with a  static main() that calls the original static method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168922/2173773) answer

Comment: [Inline::Java](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call other static methods than `main()` in a Java class from Perl. A workaround is to wrap the static method inside another class with a static main() that calls the original static method, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168922/2173773) answer. For example:

**SampleClass.java**:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
       String result = SampleMethod("string1", "string2");
       System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }

    public static String SampleMethod(final String arg1, final String arg2)
        throws Exception
     {
         return arg1 + " " + arg2;
     }
}
```

**p.pl**:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $wrap_name = 'Wrapper';
my $source = <<"END_JAVA";
class $wrap_name {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String result = SampleClass.SampleMethod("string1", "string2");
        System.out.print("Result: " + result);
    }
}
END_JAVA

my $fn = $wrap_name . '.java';
open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
print $fh $source;
close $fh;
system 'javac', $fn;
my $output = `java ${wrap_name}`;
say "Got output: '$output'";
```

You can then run:

```
$ javac SampleClass.java
$ perl p.pl
Got output: 'Result: string1 string2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In the similar way can we call static SampleMethod which is outside main method in SampleClass.java which calls "func" as the requirement is to remove the Syso statements in main method.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The current script is calling `SampleMethod()` in `SampleClass`. Please clarify

Comment: my SampleClass.java is like  public class SampleClass
{
   public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception   
   {
       var_1 = func(arg1,arg2);       
       System.out.print(var_1);
    }
    private static String func(final String arg1, final String arg2)
    throws Exception
    { 

        <--- code -->

        return value;
     }

     public static String SampleMethod(final String arg1, final String arg2)
     throws Exception
     {     
         var_2 = func(arg1,arg2);
         return var_2;
     }
}

Comment: Can I also be able to call SampleMethod through wrapper though it is not in main method ?

Comment: Yes the wrapper is calling `SampleMethod()`. See line #9 in the perl script above

Comment: I have applied the changes  but found SampleClass is in jar file so I m getting Unable to load SampleClass error. Tried using Java::Import but getting Can't locate java.pm in @INC errror. Please advise.

Comment: *"Can't locate java.pm in @INC errror."* Can you upload the perl script you used somewhere? Then I will have a look at it. Alternatively you can send it to me by email.

Comment: Can we import the jar which has SampleClass.java  to the program snippet suggested ?

Comment: *"but found SampleClass is in jar file.. "* What is the name of the jar file? Is it loacted in the same directory as the perl script?

Comment: *"Can we import the jar which has SampleClass.java to the program snippet suggested?"* : Yes, please provide information about the name of the .jar file, its location relative to the perl script, and which package `SampleClass` belongs to

Comment: Perl script Location : /opt/apps/batch/scripts/perl/    Jar location : /opt/apps/batch/utilities/Utilities.jar  Package : com.utilties.SampleClass   Perl Version : v5.16.3

Comment: Thanks, can you try this Perl script: https://pastebin.com/YfTSyzE9

Comment: Hi , one qq in the line 21 is it $fn or ${wrap_name} and after trying both i am getting com.utilties does not exist error.

Comment: *"i am getting com.utilties does not exist error"* Try adding a `-cp` option to `java` also, see line 21 in the updated version: https://pastebin.com/YfTSyzE9

Comment: Hi , I have replaced import with package in line 7 and now i am seeing "Could not find or load main class wrapper" error. Please advise.

Comment: *"I have replaced import with package in line 7"* Can you first try the change in my previous comment?

Comment: "Could not find or load main class Wrapper"  this is error after replacing.

Comment: *"Could not find or load main class Wrapper*" : Did it compile the Wrapper.java file at line 20? Is there a file Wrapper.class in the current directory ?

Comment: yes , I can see Wrapper.class in the directory where i executed the script.

Comment: Ok..Maybe we should first try delete it in case it was an earlier version. Then run the perl script and see if it generates a new one or not

Comment: Yeah i ran again , it created wrapper.class and wrapper.java but getting same error.

Comment: Good. Can you run the command on line 21 manually? Try run `java -cp .:/opt/apps/batch/utilities/Utilities.jar Wrapper` from the terminal window

Comment: Manual check is also giving the same error. Executed manually by removing the Wrapper* in the path.

Comment: When you execute manually you should not remove `Wrapper.class`. Please try again

Comment: Tried that too .. but still getting same error.

Comment: What is the content of the current directory? Type `ls` for example. There should be a file there called `Wrapper.class` ?

Comment: Yeah it's there which got generated while running the perl script after that i ran the command manually and Wrapper.class is there .

Comment: Do we need to use import statement or package statement in the $source file.

Comment: yes there is an `import com.utilties;` statement at line 7, see https://pastebin.com/YfTSyzE9

Comment: Can you try run java without the `-cp` option: Try run just `java Wrapper`. It should give you an import error

Comment: I have removed the older Wrapper.class and Wrapper.java and ran java Wrapper by removing the -cp option . This time got the compilation error package com.utilties does not exist.

Comment: Good, and if you add the `-cp` option what error do you then get? This command: `java -cp .:/opt/apps/batch/utilities/Utilities.jar Wrapper`

Comment: Using import statement in line 7 is giving package com.utilties does not exist with both java Wrapper and java -cp. If i replace import keyword with package in line 7 then it is getting compiled and saying "Could not find or load Wrapper"

Comment: So it cannot find `com.utilties` package inside `Utilities.jar` ? Maybe you need to import the class instead of the package? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460375/2173773) answer. Can you try replace `import  com.utilties` with `import  com.utilties.SampleClass;` ?

Comment: See my updated source: https://pastebin.com/YfTSyzE9

Comment: It Worked this time. Thank you very much for all the support provided.